# Random Sorting not working with paging in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater in my page and Paging is implemented in it using PagedDatasource as repeater doesn't have inbuilt paging feature.

Issue is that, My dataset has a list which is sorted randomly from SQL itself. So, when I go to next page, there is a large probability of repeating the records of previous pages as the databind() will be executed everytime the page is changed.

Any idea of how to resolve this repeatation issue?

Comment: so, actually, random sorting **is** working

Comment: Yes.. but logically it's not correct.. repeating the same records on different pages is not correct..

Comment: The computer is doing what you are asking, pagination on a random ordered source. @Kev suggested some alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- Store the randomly sorted data in memory somewhere (session, for
  example) and use that as your datasource, so it gets it from the DB
  the first time then from memory when you're paging it.
  **Beware that this is going to be very expensive when fetching a lot of data**; or
- Change the way you sort your data